# When using the jQuery UI Autocomplete with the extension point _renderMenu nested selects do not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

How do you get the jQuery UI Autocomplete to allow a nested selects when using the extension point _renderMenu. The select displays correctly but does not appear to respond to input.

```
    $.widget("custom.autocompleteheader", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
        var self = this;
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            self._renderItemData(ul, item);
            if (index == 0) ul.prepend('<li class="header-auto"> Header for autocomplete!!<select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></li>');
        });
    }
});
```

I've a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d600burton/rMkER/19/) demonstrating this. (This, well something similar, did work in version 1.8.19 (which i'm upgrading from))